# Using Berkeley DB APIs as cache solution for Spring+JPA application (DB2)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, berkeley-db

Our application deals with millions of records and we use spring with jpa.

Currently we are exploring on the feasibility to use Berkeley database in our application and as couldn't find much solutions available googling.

We would like to know whether any of BDB APIs can be used in caching the data retrieved from DB2 database, we want to do that to increase the performance much way better since the data will grow on a daily basis.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you require BerkeleyDB specifically, or would any efficient on-disk storage manager do?

Comment: And are you using a specific JPA implementation, and if so, which one?

Comment: An L2 cache in JPA caches Java objects. BerkeleyDB does not. So clarify how you think it can mimic an L2 cache?

Comment: @Tom - we are using hibernate.

Comment: @Nucleus - When the data is retrieved from DB2, I would to like to use BDB as a database which can store the retrieved data and use it for processing. Why it thought of this is because of efficient retrieval in BDB? Else if you can suggest me whether I can replace Db2 with BDB that would be fine for me too. But i need a real time user's experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything in BerkeleyDB itself that is geared towards this, nor anything in JPA itself that lets you attach caches. Rather, there are interfaces in the various implementations for plugging in caches - hence, the answer will rather depend on which JPA implementation you're using.

Based on a quick look, it seems neither OpenJPA nor EclipseLink have any way to use an on-disk cache, but Hibernate can use a variety of cache providers, of which EHCache and OSCache have on-disk options. I don't know about other implementations.